# Calling external script and automating user input with subprocess.communicate()

Tags: python, shell

I'm new to programming and have been struggling with this problem for the better part of a week now.

I need to write a program that loops through every file in a directory, calls an external command line based Perl script with an environment file to perform calculations on the data within that file, automatically assigns user inputs, and then captures the output.  I thought something like PyAutoGUI would be enough to control the command line for user inputs, but apparently it doesn't work like that.  Anyway, nothing is working and I can't find any help for my specific problem.  Here's my best shot:

```
os.path.join("Files_for_calculations")
    for files in os.listdir("Files_for_calculations"):
    for file in files:
        in_file = str(file)
        print "Executing calculations on " + str(file) + " ..."
        in_file = str(files)
        args = ["1", "%s" % in_file, "5", "4", "-1.6", "8", "alloy-liquid", "0", "4", "0"] #these are supposed to be the user inputs
        subprocess.command(["perl", "run_commands.comand -f a", args], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems here.

```
os.path.join("Files_for_calculations")
```

This line has no effect.  `os.path.join` is for splicing together the parts of a file path.  Since you are only giving one piece of the path, there is nothing to splice.  Even if there were, all this function does is to construct and return the path.  It doesn't change the working directory.  I'm not sure what you want to do, but this isn't it.

```
for files in os.listdir("Files_for_calculations"):
    for file in files:
```

(Indentation corrected.)  You don't want two loops here.  `os.listdir` will return a list of file names. If these are directories, you need to call `os.listdir` on them again.  If they're just files, as I suspect, then the second loop will give you a list of all the letters in the names.

I think you probably mean

```
for infile in os.listdir("Files_for_calculations"):
```

and you don't want the second loop at all.  I changed "file" to "infile" because in python 2, `file` is a built-in type and you shouldn't overwrite it.

The line

```
in_file = str(file)
```

is pointless, since file is already a string. Similarly, in the definition of args, you don't need `"%s" % in_file`, because in_file is a string already.  This isn't an error, but it makes the code harder to read.  Just use `in_file`.

I don't know perl, so I can't say anything about the call to subrocess.command.

Comment: Additionally, the name of the Perl script probably isn't the string with spaces that you are passing in. And you are passing `args` as a list within a list, where you should have a plain flat list. Try `c = ["perl", "run_commands.comand", "-f", "a"].append(args)` and `subprocess.command(c, shell=False, ...)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  Yeah, the bit I provided isn't exactly all of the script and the formatting got sloppy when I tried to bring in the code from my editor, I did my best to generalize it.  I'll add your suggestions and see if anything stabilizes...